# Printing pdf - letter size changed

Tags: fontsize, printing

I created my LaTeX pdf with Texniccenter. I want to give the pdf to some people, but only some specific sites. So I printed the sites I wanted to a pdf printer. However, the size of the letters seems to have changed, it's slightly bigger. 
My original latex pdf has an (Embedded Subset) Type 3 font and around 12 fonts in the form "IIXOHC+CMMI12 (Embedded Subset)" type 1 fonts.
The font seems to be the same, but the bigger letters look horrible.

Look at the two images:

[image]

and

[image]

The first image is a screenshot from text of the original pdf, the second from the printed pdf with the same zoom.
I tried lots of programs, looked into their options, but couldn't find the reason why this happens. I also didn't select auto scale or auto rotate for that matter.

So, what did I do wrong? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The presence of Type3 fonts makes me think you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but no matching Type1 font for the EC fonts (the T1 encoded version of Computer Modern). Try installing the CM-Super package (how to do it depends on your TeX distribution) or adding `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Please, more details about the original file (MWE) and the printing process to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The suggestion from egreg helped, using lmodern fixed the problem.

Comment: @egreg Sounds like your comment is the answer

Answer (score 2):

The presence of Type3 fonts makes me think you have

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but no matching Type1 font for the EC fonts (that is, the T1 encoded version of Computer Modern). Try installing the CM-Super package (how to do it depends on your TeX distribution) or adding

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

that will load the Latin Modern fonts (a clone of Computer Modern).